# Raster size Out of Range error even if within Capabilities' Lower and Upper Corner

Tags: extents, wcs, getcoverage

I'm fairly new at WCS so bear with me if this is a really stupid question, but I can't really understand the problem. I'm trying to retrieve some DEM data from the Italian Ministry of Environment's freely available datasets, which are structured as a Web Coverage Service.

In the capabilities of the dataset I'm interested into (http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/wcs/dtm_75m?service=WCS&request=GetCapabilities)
it clearly states that the Bounding Box limits are the following:

```
<ows:WGS84BoundingBox dimensions="2">
<ows:LowerCorner>6.53911455679 35.2154346311</ows:LowerCorner>
<ows:UpperCorner>19.6147808261 47.1364182243</ows:UpperCorner>
</ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
```

But if I try to send the following GetCoverage request:

```
http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms_ogc/wcs/dtm_75m.map&service=WCS&version=1.1.2&request=GetCoverage&Identifier=EL.DTM.75M&BoundingBox=10.27,41.80,13.36,43.72,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&format=image/tiff
```

The server keeps returning me this error:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" version="1.1.2" xml:lang="en-US"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1  http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="width/height" locator="InvalidParameterValue">
<ows:ExceptionText>
 msWCSGetCoverage(): WCS server error. Raster size out of range, width and height of resulting coverage must be no more than MAXSIZE=2048.
</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Why is that? Where's the error?

I tried also to swap Lon and Lat duplets or give them in the Cartesian coordinates of the dataset, but to no avail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like the service may not be responding to WCS 1.1.2 request parameters.  It does respond to a 1.0.0 request even though this version is not advertised like:

[WCS 1.0.0 request to DTM_75m service](http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/wcs/dtm%5f75m?service=WCS&request=GetCoverage&Identifier=EL.DTM.75M&version=1.1.2&format=image/png&CRS=urn%3aogc%3adef%3acrs%3aEPSG%3a:4326&BBOX=35.2154346311,6.53911455679,47.1364182243,19.6147808261&width=45&height=45&)

Comment: Thanks nmtoken: I've tried to modify my query with 1.0.0 instead of 1.1.2 and image/png instead than image/tiff (as it appears the only possibility from the xml you linked), but the server replies with a "mapserv.exe" 1Kb file: I tried to change its extension, but to no avail (it cannot be a geoimage weighting only 1 Kb). Do I need to change something else to make my request compliant to WCS 1.0.0 standards?

Comment: `mapserv.exe` is possibly an error message (XML/text file); despite the name,  try opening in a text editor